# Catalog (name,path,version) files via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, authentication, remote-server

I am trying to catalog a set of files over multiple remote servers. Setting up a mapped drive is not an option at this time. Furthermore, I am not a hundred percent sure all drives available for mapping. I am only interested in just logical drives, no network or usb or anything of the like. I think I mostly have it, but being new to PowerShell I am not sure how to implement my current working script to loop through a set of remote servers.

My current working script is as follows and works great if local to the system:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType = 3" | 
Select-Object DeviceID | 
ForEach-Object {Get-Childitem ($_.DeviceID + "\") -include file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt -recurse} | 
./get-fileversion.ps1
```

I have found several references on how to connect to remote systems like the following:
[get-FileVersion Source](http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/792-powershell-script-find-pst-files-on-remote-computers)

where it uses a file to list the server (easy to understand) but I also need to pass credentials to each server and would like to execute the script above on each server.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thank you in advance!

`get-fileversion.ps1` source:

found at http://jtruher3.wordpress.com/2006/05/14/powershell-and-file-version-information/
on 2014-11-11

```
param ( [string[]]$paths )
begin {
    # I want to do some stuff with relative paths.   
    # create a variable that I can use later
    $P = [string](get-location)

    # the workhorse of the script
    function GetVersionInfo
    {
        param ( [string]$path )
        # resolve the path, we're going to need a fully qualified path to hand
        # to the method, so go get it.  I may not have that depending on how
        # was called
        $rpath = resolve-path $path 2>$null
        # the thing we hand to the method is the path string, so we'll tuck that away
        $path = $rpath.path
        # check to be sure that we're in the filesystem
        if ( $rpath.provider.name -ne "FileSystem" ) 
        { 
            "$path is not in the filesystem"
            return $null
        }
        # now that I've determined that I'm in the filesystem, go get the fileversion
        $o = [system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo]::GetVersionInfo($path)
        # this little dance adds a new property to the versioninfo object
        # I add the relative path to the versioninfo so I can inspect that in the output object
        # the way that add-member works is to not emit the object, so I need to 
        # use the -passthrough parameter
        $o|add-member noteproperty RelativePath ($path.replace($P,".")) -pass
    }
    # whoops! something bad happened
    function ShowFileError
    {
        param ( [string]$path )
        if ( test-path $path -pathtype container )
        {
            "$path is a container"
        }
        else
        {
            "$path not found"
        }
    }
}

# data could have been piped - check $_ to see if this cmdlet had data
# piped to it
process {
    if ( $_ )
    {
        # make sure that I'm not trying to get a versioninfo of a directory
        if ( test-path $_ -pathtype leaf )
        {
            GetVersionInfo $_
        }
        else
        {
            ShowFileError $_
        }
    }
}

# we could have also gotten arguments on the command line
end {
    if ( $paths )
    {
        # by calling resolve path first, I can deal with wildcards on the command line
        foreach ( $path in resolve-path $paths )
        {
            # make sure it's a file, not a directory
            if ( test-path $path -pathtype leaf )
            {
                GetVersionInfo $path
            }
            else
            {
                ShowFileError $path
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a script called **Get-Info.ps1** with this content:

```
$Report = @{}

# check free disk space
$Report.Disks = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | where Free | select Name, Used, Free
# this is just an example, collect whatever info you want from each machine
# and add it to the $Report object:
# $Report.MoreInfo = 'Foo'

[pscustomobject] $Report
```

And a list of target computers in **computers.txt** which all have a common account with permissions,
you can run

```
Invoke-Command "Get-Info.ps1" -ComputerName (gc computers.txt) -Credential (Get-Credential) -AsJob | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```